# How do I run Gnome 3 sound control from KDE?

Tags: debian, gnome, kde, audio

Skype is using pulse audio, which is part of Gnome and the main place I found to configure microphones was in the standard Gnome sound control.

How can I configure the microphones from KDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PulseAudio is not GNOME-specific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_Audio), but if I interpret your question correctly, you're looking for KDE tools to configure PulseAudio.  See [the PulseAudio page on the KDE wiki](http://userbase.kde.org/PulseAudio) and maybe also [veromix-plasmoid](http://code.google.com/p/veromix-plasmoid/) (and probably [the “Perfect setup” page in the PulseAudio wiki](http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/PerfectSetup) but it looks down to me).  Judging from [Fedora's PulseAudio KDE Integration efforts](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/KDE_PulseAudio_Integration), `kmix` should actually already do what you're looking for.

Comment: Please don't write “see this”, as it becomes completely meaningless if the link goes away. Writing at least a short description helps a lot to find the content again if it gets moved around.